# File uploader uploading files but displaying error

Tags: php, file, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipart

**My code**

I've got this multipart form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Select:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"> 
<br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Which points to this file:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("mp4", "avi","mpeg","wmv","swf","3gp","AVI");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (!in_array($extension, $allowedExts) || $_FILES['file']['error']>0  || file_exists(date("YmdHis").$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{  
   echo "Error [code: ".$_FILES['file']['error']."]";
} else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      date("YmdHis").$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo 'file uploaded'; 
}
?>
```

**What it should do**

Uploading video files

**What's not working**

I've tried to upload an .AVI video of about 300kb: it was uploaded, but the error message "Error [code: ]" was shown

**Result of `error_reporting(E_ALL);`**

> Notice: Undefined index: file in upload.php on line 5 
>  Notice:
>   Undefined index: file in upload.php on line 8

**Result of `var_dump($_POST,$_FILES);` (with "password" field empty)**

```
array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

**Result of `"<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);`**

```
Array ( )
```

**Where I tried the code**

- Local server run with easyPHP, php version 5.5.8
- Shared server, php version 5.3.10

**My question**

How can I display the success message correctly and solve the problem?

Comment: are u trying to upload multiple files?

Comment: Nope, just one per time

Comment: is it showing the error and uploading the file together?

Comment: Yes, it uploads the file but it shows the error message

Comment: This is a guess. Change the 'or' test to '||'. This will allow 'short circuit' evaluation of the tests. i.e. the first 'true' result will end the sequence of tests. Currently all the test will be evaluated.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for your help. I changed the code as you said, but it's not working anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run your code on PHP 5.3.18. windows XP. Assuming that upload limits are met. The only issue i can find is that you have missed a 'destination' directory from the 'target file name' when moving the files.

Tested sample code:

```
<?php // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115575/file-uploader-uploading-files-but-displaying-error?noredirect=1#comment39103445_25115575
$destDir = 'P:/temp/';
$allowedExts = array("mp4", "avi","mpeg","wmv","swf","3gp","avi");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (!in_array($extension, $allowedExts) || $_FILES['file']['error']>0  || file_exists(date("YmdHis").$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
   echo "Error [code: ".$_FILES['file']['error']."]";

} else {
      $newFilename = $destDir . date("YmdHis").$_FILES["file"]["name"];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      $newFilename);
      echo 'file uploaded : ', $newFilename;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried editing $destdir using: the complete simulated url (localhost), the real absolute path of the folder on my pc and the relative path; the complete url of my hosted website and the relative path; but I always get error code 0

Comment: Oh, stupid me. I was insisting to try with the video with .AVI extension, but I didn't think PHP considers it != from .avi (which is in the array of allowed extensions), so your code actually works, it was just me. Feel free to call me fool. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Angelo, glad you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because of the file sieze. -

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = allowed max size

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = allowed max size
```

- [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited post_max_size from 2M (so it would have been sufficent anyway to upload the 300kb video) to 40M and post_max_size from 8M to 40M, but the behaviour didn't change. Please note that, actually, the video **was** uploaded, but I got the error message anyway.

Comment: I tried also setting "max size" as said in your new answer, it's not working anyway